# Paging through a list of objects and repopulating using JQuery,AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have a list of objects and I would like to create my own custom control that pages through the list using Jquery to make the Ajax calls to my pager methods. I've had some experience with Jquery but need a helping hand and I really don't want to use update panels etc. So the scenario is.....user clicks next, the C# method is called using Ajax, the code gets the relevant data and sends re-populates the UI with the next item in the list.

If anyone knows any good sites or anything please let me know!

Cheers

Louis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [jQuery pagination plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-pagination) that does paginate your JSON data.

and i also i used asp.net mvc and linq to sql to do a similar sample and it is well shown in this SO question [Json Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174249/is-this-a-valid-jquery-callback-function-call)

Comment: Unfortunately I am working on a webforms site :( I have looked at the jquery plug in, it's very cool but can't be used for this situation. I am looking to page through a list of Objects that will be used to populate a control that contains textboxes, drop downs etc. Is there anything suitable out there using JQuery?

Comment: Apologies Pandiya, this is super cool! It's exactly what I'm looking for and more! Thanks!

Comment: found another good one: http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-pagination-system/