# Good Reusable, centralized AJAX component based on jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, reusability

I ofetn find myself writing the same code in jquery for ajax stuff. Still i can't find a good
Reusable, centralized AJAX component based on jQuery...

**Note:** 
One similar question i had asked before [Reusable jquery ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173842/reusable-jquery-ajax-requests) but it had some issues.

Comment: What things do you find yourself repeating currently?

Comment: @Nick look at the link i ve posted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the reason you can't find one is because that's what $.ajax() **is** at its heart.

Sounds like your best bet would be to use modular coding techniques to make simple functions as wrappers for things you find yourself duplicating, then include them in a common js file.

If you just want something that feels jQueryish to use, you could make it as a plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring